# change screen resolution of server which runs robot framework tests from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, server, virtual-machine, robotframework

I am currently running our robot framework UI tests via jenkins overnight.

Quite a few fail because the screen resolution it runs up in is 1024 x 768 but the tests tend to be written by people working in 1920 x 1024.

I was trying to find a way to get the server to run them on a larger screen resolution. It's a VM and I have tried setting the VM console to 1680x1050 which works for when connected on but the tests still run up in the lower resolution.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you use "Set Window Size" keyword to set the width and height of browser from the test.

Comment: This works for me locally, I can change the browser window size. However, when running it on the server is still opens in 1024 x 768 - even after running this keyword.

I think its a server issue where it seems to be limiting the resolution and i'm not sure why.

Comment: I have also faced same issue when I used selenium grid to run testcases on node machines. I did two things: 1. Set the screen resolution while starting node and 2. setting screen size from testcase. How r u running ur testcase through selenium grid or directly?

Comment: running directly.

How did you set the resolution of the node?

Comment: You can set screen width and height using docker. Please refer this https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium#screen-size